# Spring @PostConstruct function in a @Repository called multiple times

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a DAO that I'm trying to inject into a couple different places:

```
@Repository
public class FooDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private HibernateManager sessionFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomeDatabaseStuff() throws DataAccessException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And my application-context.xml is a fairly simple context:component-scan:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd" default-init-method="init" default-destroy-method="destroy">

     <context:component-scan base-package="top.level"/>
</beans>
```

The DAO is accessed from a couple servlets in my application server through @Autowired properties. As far as I understand, anything annotated with @Repository should default to being a singleton and thus doSomeDatabaseStuff() should only be called once (as is my intention). The problem is that I'm seeing doSomeDatabaseStuff() called multiple times.

What's going on here? Have I set something up incorrectly? I'm using spring 3.0.0.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: I have a few servlets that all have the same xml config file shown above. Will a new FooDAO instance get constructed for each servlet? If so, how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your doSomeDatabaseStuff() and check the stack trace? This might help you find out where it's being called from. It might be too hard to understand all the spring stuff, but it could be illuminating.

Comment: @John: It looks like it's being called from a few different places, only one of which is the init function of one of my servlets.

Comment: You could also look at the value of `this` to see if it really is the same object, or whether multiple instances are being created.

Comment: The debugger shows different ids, so it looks like different instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a few servlets that all have the same xml config file shown above

this means you mean multiple spring contexts, and that in turn means that multiple instances are created (for each context).

You need *only one* spring context - i.e. only one xml config (`applicationContext.xml`)

Read [this tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) to see how you should setup Spring MVC.

Comment: I don't really understand how to do that. Don't I have to have a [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in my WEB-INF/ for each servlet? How can I make all of them use the same beans?